# How to get Notification for auto-renewal subscription with RMStore in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, auto-renewing, receipt-validation, rmstore

In my iOS app I have used auto-renewal subscription. We need a solution for cross platform. I'm using **RMStore** in iOS for purchasing product.

**In current scenario**: I am getting latest receipts from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and validate to AppStore with `RMStoreAppReceiptVerifier` than an update expiry date to a server. We update to server data all the time from both platforms (iOS and Android). And from iOS side, we have to check receipt all times when the app is launched. When I get push notification when payment is renewed? If it is possible, then we have updated server data at that time

**Q-1)** How can I check my new Renew process is done?

**Q-2)** if User canceled their auto-renew subscription from iTunes, how can I be notified so I can update my database? Do I need a daemon that checks, expired subscriptions to see if the user renewed?

**Q-3)** in iOS. If I logged in from another device, then how can I verify receipt from another device?

Please Suggest me How can I handle auto-renewal Subscription in cross platform with using server Database. I'm hoping someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: did you solve this?